# IDataProtector protect and unprotect strings

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption

I refered to this link for session protection in Asp.Net core app (blazor server):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

But after injecting IDataProtector to a component, protect and unprotect methods only get byte[] as parameter, I want to use strings for protect and unprotect methods, like it is showed in above link.
what namespaces or packages or any other work is required to enable string protection in this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection namespace in my .netcore3.1 app.
I see protector.Protect(), protector.Unprotect() under class DataProtectionCommonExtensions accepting string as parameter.

I referred to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlHDTQhVYoI) before I came across the documentation mentioned in the OP.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection {

    public static class DataProtectionCommonExtensions{

        public static string Protect(this IDataProtector protector, string plaintext);

        public static string Unprotect(this IDataProtector protector, string protectedData);

    }
}
```